# How can I fix this CUDA / Darknet installation error?

Tags: python, linux, darknet

I'm trying to install [darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) on Google Collab, and in doing so I ran the following code / commands:

```
!git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet
!apt-get update
!apt-get upgrade
!apt-get install build-essential
!apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
!apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-d
!apt-get install libopencv-dev
%cd darknet
!ls
!sed -i 's/OPENCV=0/OPENCV=1/g' Makefile
!sed -i 's/GPU=0/GPU=1/g' Makefile
!ls
%cd ../
!ls
!apt install g++-5
!apt install gcc-5
!apt update
!apt upgrade
import tensorflow as tf
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
!/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --version
%cd darknet
!wget https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights
!make
!./darknet detect cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/person.jpg
def imShow(path):
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
image = cv2.imread(path)
height, width = image.shape[:2]
resized_image = cv2.resize(image,(3width, 3height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18, 10)
plt.axis("off")
#plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 5]
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(resized_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
def upload():
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
for name, data in uploaded.items():
with open(name, 'wb') as f:
f.write(data)
print ('saved file', name)
def download(path):
from google.colab import files
files.download(path)
imShow('/content/drive/My Drive/face/img/bv.jpg')
```

From that string of commands, it returns the following error:

```
CUDA status Error: file: ./src/dark_cuda.c : () : line: 239 : build time: Jun 16 2020 - 20:18:49 

 CUDA Error: invalid argument
CUDA Error: invalid argument: File exists
darknet: ./src/utils.c:326: error: Assertion `0' failed.
```

I've tried installing this before, and it worked previously. Apparently, there may have been a recent update which caused this bug, but I'm not sure.

Comment: https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/1930

Comment: But i cant even install darknet and problem is not in weigbts or cfg